# System.WindowsRuntimeExtensions missing?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await

I'm trying to expose an async method via a windows RT component to my consuming JS.

Without going into too much initial detail, some of the articles I've read point to an extension method `AsAsyncOperation()` which should be available on `Task<T>` (example article here: http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/how-to-expose-async-methods-in-a-windows-runtime-component/ )

Here's the MSDN link for it, so I know it should exist!:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.aspx

What is confusing me at the moment is that I simple don't seem to have the 'AsAyncOperation' function at all.
Is there anything I need to do to ensure these extension methods are available?

Comment: Exposing generic types in a component is a very lossy proposition, particularly to a language that doesn't support it at all.  At least post a snippet of the code you are trying to get working so we have some context.

Comment: Do you have `using System;` in your C# file?

Comment: I think that was the one svick, thank you very much! I'm guessing that due to the AsAyncOperation() being an extension method the compiler couldn't recommend me a 'using', as a side point, why is that?

Comment: I have noticed your question you are asking about "AsAyncOperation" it's wrong spelling right one is `AsAsyncOperation`. So I suggest you to check the spelling.

Comment: Good spot @Xyroid but that was purely a translation error, svick was correct, just wondered as a side point why ctrl+. never picks up a 'using' when the method which isn't found is an extension.